# Iterable pytorch dataset with multiple workers

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, distributed

So I have a text file bigger than my ram memory, I would like to create a dataset in PyTorch that reads line by line, so I don't have to load it all at once in memory. I found pytorch `IterableDataset` as potential solution for my problem. It only works as expected when using 1 worker, if using more than one worker it will create duplicate recods. Let me show you an example:

Having a `testfile.txt` containing:

```
0 - Dummy line
1 - Dummy line
2 - Dummy line
3 - Dummy line
4 - Dummy line
5 - Dummy line
6 - Dummy line
7 - Dummy line
8 - Dummy line
9 - Dummy line
```

Defining a IterableDataset:

```py
class CustomIterableDatasetv1(IterableDataset):

    def __init__(self, filename):

        #Store the filename in object's memory
        self.filename = filename

    def preprocess(self, text):

        ### Do something with text here
        text_pp = text.lower().strip()
        ###

        return text_pp

    def line_mapper(self, line):
        
        #Splits the line into text and label and applies preprocessing to the text
        text, label = line.split('-')
        text = self.preprocess(text)

        return text, label


    def __iter__(self):

        #Create an iterator
        file_itr = open(self.filename)

        #Map each element using the line_mapper
        mapped_itr = map(self.line_mapper, file_itr)
        
        return mapped_itr
```

We can now test it:

```py
base_dataset = CustomIterableDatasetv1("testfile.txt")
#Wrap it around a dataloader
dataloader = DataLoader(base_dataset, batch_size = 1, num_workers = 1)
for X, y in dataloader:
    print(X,y)
```

It outputs:

```
('0',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('1',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('2',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('3',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('4',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('5',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('6',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('7',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('8',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('9',) (' Dummy line',)
```

That is correct. But If I change the number of workers to 2 the output becomes

```
('0',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('0',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('1',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('1',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('2',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('2',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('3',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('3',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('4',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('4',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('5',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('5',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('6',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('6',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('7',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('7',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('8',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('8',) (' Dummy line\n',)
('9',) (' Dummy line',)
('9',) (' Dummy line',)
```

Which is incorrect, as is creating duplicates of each sample per worker in the data loader.

Is there a way to solve this issue with pytorch? So a dataloader can be created to not load all file in memory with support for multiple workers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I found an answer within the torch discuss forum https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/iterable-pytorch-dataset-with-multiple-workers/135475/3 where they pointed out I should be using the worker info to slice consecutively to the batch size.

The new dataset would look like this:

```py
class CustomIterableDatasetv1(IterableDataset):

    def __init__(self, filename):

        #Store the filename in object's memory
        self.filename = filename

    def preprocess(self, text):

        ### Do something with text here
        text_pp = text.lower().strip()
        ###

        return text_pp

    def line_mapper(self, line):
        
        #Splits the line into text and label and applies preprocessing to the text
        text, label = line.split('-')
        text = self.preprocess(text)

        return text, label


    def __iter__(self):
        worker_total_num = torch.utils.data.get_worker_info().num_workers
        worker_id = torch.utils.data.get_worker_info().id
        #Create an iterator
        file_itr = open(self.filename)

        #Map each element using the line_mapper
        mapped_itr = map(self.line_mapper, file_itr)
        
        #Add multiworker functionality
        mapped_itr = itertools.islice(mapped_itr, worker_id, None, worker_total_num)

        return mapped_itr
```

Special thanks to @Ivan who also pointed out the slicing solution.

With two workers it returns the same data as 1 worker only

Comment: An edit would have been preferred... Regardless please consider upvoting the original answer.

Comment: Where does the dataset get the `num_workers` parameter from? I'm trying to test this class in isolation and I just get an error that `worker_total_num` is `None`.

Comment: When you wrap this under a dataloader i believe it gains that parameter, this was the case when i coded it, dont know how is it for recent torch releases.

Comment: Have you had success with this on multi-GPU boxes? We used your logic with `islice` and it is working in the sense that it is splitting data correctly between workers. But we are not getting any speedup when using multiple GPUs, which seems odd.

Comment: @eljiwo Yes, that is the case.

Comment: I would recommend you to detect what is the bottleneck in your system then, if faster dataloaders arent giving you any speedup it would mean they were fast enough already to be always ready for the gpu. Profile your training and if you share some info about it i may be able to help

Answer (score 6):

You have access to the worker identifier inside the `Dataset`'s `__iter__` function using the [`torch.utils.data.get_worker_info`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.get_worker_info) util. This means you can step through the iterator and add an offset depending on the worker *id*. You can wrap an iterator with [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) which allows you to step a `start` index as well as a `step`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
class DS(IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __iter__(self):
        uid = torch.utils.data.get_worker_info().id
        itr = islice(range(10), uid, None, self.batch_size)
        return itr
```

Looping through the data loader will yield unique instances even though we are using `num_workers > 1`:

```
>>> for x in DataLoader(DS(batch_size=2), batch_size=2, num_workers=2):
...     print(x)
tensor([0, 2])
tensor([1, 3])
tensor([4, 6])
tensor([5, 7])
tensor([8])
tensor([9])
```

---

In your case you can do:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        # create an iterator
        file_itr = open(self.filename)

        # map each element using the line_mapper
        mapped_itr = map(self.line_mapper, file_itr)
    
        # wrap the iterator
        step_itr = islice(mapped_itr, uid, None, self.batch_size)

        return step_itr
```

Comment: How could you add this logic to the file reading? I understand how you do it with the list you already have defined, but what about reading the file on the go?

Comment: I don't really get it, isn't your iterable dataset implemented and working with `num_workers=1` yet?

Comment: Yes, but you are indexing based on the `uid` while creating the iterator, not after the iterator is created. Thats why I dont follow how to put this on top of my current IterableDataset

Comment: The `__iter__` function is called by the data loader, for each worker *when* the data loader is first looped over. Have you tried returning `iter(list(mapped_itr)[uid::self.batch_size])` in your `__iter__` function?

Comment: But if you call `list(mapped_itr)` you will consume the full iterator, thus reading the whole file in memory, this is something im trying to avoid as the file is bigger than my RAM. Wouldnt it?

Comment: Indeed you're right, I've edited my answer using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

Comment: One change as well needed, instead of self.batch_size when slicing it should be num of workers.

Comment: How does `IterableDataset` have access to the batch size given to the `DataLoader`?